# I keep getting an error in my script about the verable

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I keep getting this error

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1' in C:\wamp\www\notaryaccounting\contact.php on line 6

I can not figure out way. In the contact.php if I replace the $_POST['parentVal'] with the number 1 the script works. So it has something to do with the passing of the parentVal variable from the jquery script.

When I set it up with $_GET['parentVal'] and I use the Developer tools I can see the variable is there So the script should work but it doesn't.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){                    
                $('#parent').change(function(){ //on change event
                var parentVal = $('#parent').val(); //<----- get the value from the parent select
                $.ajax({
                    url     : 'contact.php', //the url you are sending datas to which will again send the result
                    type    : 'POST', //type of request, GET or POST
                    data    : { parentValue: parentVal}, //Data you are sending
                    success : function(data){$('#child').html(data)}, // On success, it will populate the 2nd select
                    error   : function(){alert('an error has occured')} //error message
                })
            })

            })
    </script>
 </head>
 <body>

    Customer:
    <select name="customer" id="parent">
      <option>-Select a Customer-</option>
    <?php 

  include("connect.php");
    $pid = $_SESSION['profile']['id']; 
   foreach($db->query("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE pid = '$pid'") as $row) {
        echo "<option value=" . $row['id'] . ">" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
}
        ?>
    </select>


Contact:
<select name="contact"id="child"/>
<option>-Select a Contact-</option>
</select>



  </body>
</html>   





<?php
include("connect.php");

$custid = $_POST['parentVal'];

foreach($db->query('SELECT * FROM contact WHERE custid =' . $custid ) as $row) {
    $results.=("<option value=" . $row['id'] . ">" . $row['name'] . "</option>");
}
echo $results;
```

Comment: Try `$('#parent option:selected').val()` and also  before running query check for `$_POST['parentVal']`

Answer (score 1):

You are sending your data with `parentValue` name and in server you use `parentVal`. Change the names.

```
$_POST['parentValue'];
```

Not

```
$_POST['parentVal']
```

In addition, you have SQL syntax error:

change

```
$db->query('SELECT * FROM contact WHERE custid =' . $custid
```

To:

```
$db->query("SELECT * FROM contact WHERE custid='$custid'")
```